# trying to detect iphone x in swift always return false

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-x

I am using simulator to test my all on iphone x I have searched for method to be able to detect iPhone x but all of them return false always

this is one method of them

```
struct Device {
        // iDevice detection code
        static let IS_IPAD             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
        static let IS_IPHONE           = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        static let IS_RETINA           = UIScreen.main.scale >= 2.0

        static let SCREEN_WIDTH        = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
        static let SCREEN_HEIGHT       = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH   = Int( max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
        static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH   = Int( min(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

        static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH  < 568
        static let IS_IPHONE_5         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568
        static let IS_IPHONE_6         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667
        static let IS_IPHONE_6P        = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736
        static let IS_IPHONE_X         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812
    }
```

and this is another method

```
if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1136:
                print("iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C")
            case 1334:
                print("iPhone 6/6S/7/8")
            case 2208:
                print("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+")
            case 2436:
                print("iPhone X")
                retValue = true
            default:
                print("unknown")
            }
        }
```

why all methods return false ? is that because I am using simulator or what?

Comment: Print the result of this `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height` and share with us!

Comment: this is the value when I am using iphone x simulator = 1704.0

Comment: Here on `Xcode 9.4.1`, it prints `2436.0`. Not sure what is causing it to be `1704`

Comment: I am also using xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like below to detect iPhone X:

```
var iphoneX = false
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if ((UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top)! > CGFloat(0.0)) {
        iphoneX = true
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.top > 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
enum DeviceType {
 case iPhoneX
 case iPhone5
 case iPhone6Plus
 case iPhone6
 case Unknown
}

class Utils {

    class var isIphoneX:Bool {
        if deviceType() == .iPhoneX {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    class func deviceType()->DeviceType {
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 1136:
            return .iPhone5
        case 1334:
            return .iPhone6
        case 1920, 2208:
            return .iPhone6Plus
        case 2436:
            return .iPhoneX
        default:
            return .Unknown
       }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
if Utils.isIphoneX {
    //Do things
}
```